# problem with gunicorn [ERROR] Exception in worker process

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

A month ago I rented a Shared line cloud server on Selectel and uploaded a project there, but literally a couple of days later this error appeared (see file). Since I was unable to resolve the error, I had to reset the server and start the site again. And again, not even a day had passed before the same error appeared.

```
Feb 14 09:19:21 it-want systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Feb 14 09:19:21 it-want gunicorn[565]: [2024-02-14 09:19:21 +0000] [565] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0

Feb 14 09:19:21 it-want gunicorn[565]: [2024-02-14 09:19:21 +0000] [565] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/run/gunicorn.sock (565)
Feb 14 09:19:21 it-want gunicorn[565]: [2024-02-14 09:19:21 +0000] [565] [INFO] Using worker: sync
Feb 14 09:19:21 it-want gunicorn[566]: [2024-02-14 09:19:21 +0000] [566] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 566
Feb 14 09:19:21 it-want gunicorn[567]: [2024-02-14 09:19:21 +0000] [567] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 567
Feb 14 09:19:21 it-want gunicorn[568]: [2024-02-14 09:19:21 +0000] [568] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 568
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[568]: [2024-02-14 09:19:22 +0000] [568] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[568]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[568]:   File "/home/itwant/itwant/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[568]:     worker.init_process()
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[568]:   File "/home/itwant/itwant/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 142, in init_process
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[568]:     self.run()
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[568]:   File "/home/itwant/itwant/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 126, in run
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[568]:     self.run_for_one(timeout)
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[568]:   File "/home/itwant/itwant/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 70, in run_for_one
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[568]:     self.accept(listener)
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[568]:   File "/home/itwant/itwant/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 29, in accept
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[568]:     client, addr = listener.accept()
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[568]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 293, in accept
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[568]:     fd, addr = self._accept()
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[568]: OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[568]: [2024-02-14 09:19:22 +0000] [568] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 568)
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[566]: [2024-02-14 09:19:22 +0000] [566] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[566]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[566]:   File "/home/itwant/itwant/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[566]:     worker.init_process()
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[566]:   File "/home/itwant/itwant/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 142, in init_process
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[566]:     self.run()
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[566]:   File "/home/itwant/itwant/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 126, in run
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[566]:     self.run_for_one(timeout)
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[566]:   File "/home/itwant/itwant/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 70, in run_for_one
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[566]:     self.accept(listener)
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[566]:   File "/home/itwant/itwant/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 29, in accept
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[566]:     client, addr = listener.accept()
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[566]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 293, in accept
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[566]:     fd, addr = self._accept()
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[566]: OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[566]: [2024-02-14 09:19:22 +0000] [566] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 566)
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[567]: [2024-02-14 09:19:22 +0000] [567] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[567]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[567]:   File "/home/itwant/itwant/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[567]:     worker.init_process()
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[567]:   File "/home/itwant/itwant/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 142, in init_process
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[567]:     self.run()
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[567]:   File "/home/itwant/itwant/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 126, in run
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[567]:     self.run_for_one(timeout)
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[567]:   File "/home/itwant/itwant/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 70, in run_for_one
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[567]:     self.accept(listener)
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[567]:   File "/home/itwant/itwant/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 29, in accept
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[567]:     client, addr = listener.accept()
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[567]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 293, in accept
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[567]:     fd, addr = self._accept()
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[567]: OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[567]: [2024-02-14 09:19:22 +0000] [567] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 567)
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[565]: [2024-02-14 09:19:22 +0000] [565] [ERROR] Worker (pid:568) exited with code 255
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[565]: [2024-02-14 09:19:22 +0000] [565] [ERROR] Worker (pid:568) exited with code 255.
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[565]: [2024-02-14 09:19:22 +0000] [565] [ERROR] Worker (pid:567) exited with code 255
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[565]: [2024-02-14 09:19:22 +0000] [565] [ERROR] Worker (pid:567) exited with code 255.
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[569]: [2024-02-14 09:19:22 +0000] [569] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 569
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[565]: [2024-02-14 09:19:22 +0000] [565] [ERROR] Worker (pid:566) exited with code 255
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[565]: [2024-02-14 09:19:22 +0000] [565] [ERROR] Worker (pid:566) exited with code 255.
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[570]: [2024-02-14 09:19:22 +0000] [570] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 570
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[571]: [2024-02-14 09:19:22 +0000] [571] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 571
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[569]: [2024-02-14 09:19:22 +0000] [569] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[569]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[569]:   File "/home/itwant/itwant/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[569]:     worker.init_process()
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[569]:   File "/home/itwant/itwant/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 142, in init_process
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[569]:     self.run()
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[569]:   File "/home/itwant/itwant/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 126, in run
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[569]:     self.run_for_one(timeout)
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[569]:   File "/home/itwant/itwant/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 70, in run_for_one
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[569]:     self.accept(listener)
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[569]:   File "/home/itwant/itwant/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 29, in accept
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[569]:     client, addr = listener.accept()
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[569]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 293, in accept
Feb 14 09:19:22 it-want gunicorn[569]:     fd, addr = self._accept()
```

Comment: Without access to your code, all we can say is that something is wrong in your code. Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].